# What is the correct way to set version and SDK numbers in .NET Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I am building an app using .NET Android (formarly Xamarin.Android), but now it's not Xamarin and it's not MAUI, I can find very little to no documentation on this native Android C# development, I wonder why, considering the performance difference between this and MAUI is like day and night... Anyways, somehow I can't set TargetSDK version, or what I set is not being used in the build process by all the assemblies, something weird is happening and I don't really know what.

I tried to put the target SDK every way I could imagine, like this in the csproj:

```
<SupportedOSPlatformVersion>26.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
<TargetPlatformMinVersion>26</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
<TargetOSPlatformVersion>34</TargetOSPlatformVersion>
<TargetPlatformVersion>34</TargetPlatformVersion>
<AndroidTargetSdkVersion>34</AndroidTargetSdkVersion>
```

Like this:

```
<TargetFramework>net8.0-android34.0</TargetFramework>
```

Like this, in Android Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="26" android:targetSdkVersion="34" />
```

and these same numbers inside the application tag too.

Whatever I do, I get this warning at build time, and the resulting bundle has target sdk = 28. The warning is complaining about some assembly inside the Xamarin tooling on which everything else I suppose depends, but shouldn't it target the same thing I target my code? If not, how to fix this issue?

This is what I get when doing the release build:

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.43\targets\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Tooling.targets(69,5): warning XA1006: The TargetFram
> eworkVersion (Android API level 34) is higher than the targetSdkVersion (28). Please increase the `android:targetSdkVersion` in the `AndroidManifest.xm l` so that the API levels match. [C:\Users\xdr\source\repos\movsar\chldr\src\client\chldr_android\chldr_android.csproj]

There is no place at all in my code where I set 28 to anything!

Comment: I don't get it what are you trying to do, are you trying to setup target platform for a .net 8 Android app?

Comment: @FreakyAli yes, that too

Comment: Finally fixed the issue with setting everything in the manifest file, I tried that before too, but I was using the application tag, and it works only when I put these versions into the manifest tag. Though I still believe there must be a way to set all of that in the .csproj file

Comment: Great that you fixed it, i would suggest you add this as an answer for others looking for this in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, to fix the issue, you may need to add the following to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="34" />
```

As a summary:

`targetSdkVersion` is what your API Level app Supports, this can be different from `compileSdkVersion` since you can use runtime checks to see which API level you are on.

`minSdkVersion` is the minimum platform which supports.